# Is possible set all a atributte all elements with :checked CSS?

Tags: html, css, checked

How can I select all the elements after a checked?

```
input:checked + .box
{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

only set border a .box but i want do it to all elements after checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap all elements after the checkbox in a common element and this way they will all depend on the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="boxes-wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

And then in the CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .boxes-wrapper .box {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/TyLhnjGfwL0IKXJFcPRu?p=preview